# Help with SQL Script for connection + extended attribute

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find out which of the DB don't have active connection and the extended attribute of that DB.
I have this script that works wonderfully and creates a table with all DBs name and the amount of active connection.
Can someone please assist how to I add an additional column that will show the extended attribute called "Test" for each DB?

```
SELECT @@ServerName AS server
 ,NAME AS dbname
 ,COUNT(STATUS) AS  number_of_connections
 ,GETDATE() AS timestamp
FROM sys.databases sd
LEFT JOIN sysprocesses sp ON sd.database_id = sp.dbid
WHERE database_id NOT BETWEEN 1 AND 4
GROUP BY NAME
```

Thanks!
Effy L.

Comment: Thaks J.D.
yes an "extended property". say is called test in all of the DBs.

Comment: Hi, if you can spear the time to answer I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extended properties are database-scoped so you'll need to query values in the context of each database.

The below example uses dynamic SQL to accomplish this by qualifying `sys.extended_properties` with the name of each database and concatenating results for all databases with `UNION ALL`. This also uses `sys.dm_exec_sessions` instead of the `sysprocesses` view as [recommended in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). You may need to tweak the query according to your use case and environment (e.g. omit non-readable secondary AG replicas).

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

WITH databases AS (
    SELECT sd.name, sd.database_id
    FROM sys.databases sd 
    WHERE sd.database_id > 4 AND state_desc = 'ONLINE'
)
SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(CAST(N'
SELECT 
      @@SERVERNAME AS server
    , N' + QUOTENAME(d.name,'''') + N' AS dbname
    , (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions AS sdes WHERE sdes.database_id = ' + CAST(d.database_id AS nvarchar(10)) + N') AS number_of_connections
    , SYSDATETIME() AS timestamp
    , (SELECT value FROM ' + QUOTENAME(d.name) + N'.sys.extended_properties WHERE class_desc = N''DATABASE'' AND name = N''Test'') AS TestExtendedPropertyValue'
    AS nvarchar(MAX))
    ,' UNION ALL')
FROM databases AS d;

--SELECT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
GO
```

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful. I thank you a lot!